# How can I add a value to a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

```
I compare these two arrays:
```

$array1:

```
   array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(10000) {
            ["12345"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(46) "monkey.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(149) "Volumes/animals/monkey.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2650752"
            }
            ["678790"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "elephant.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/elephant.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
            ["23123"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "fred.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/fred.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
          }    
         [1]=>
          array(10000) {
            ["624245"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(46) "duck.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(149) "Volumes/animals/duck.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2650752"
            }
            ["934522"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "lora.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/lora.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
            ["832452"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "sam.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/sam.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
          }
        [2]=>
          array(1500) {
            ["234214"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(46) "chi.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(149) "Volumes/animals/chi.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2650752"
            }
            ["942134"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "ape.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/ape.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
            ["234234"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "cat.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/cat.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
        }
    }
```

$array2:

```
   array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(10000) {
            ["12345"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(46) "monkei.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(149) "Volumes/animals/monkey.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2650752"
            }
            ["678790"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "elephant.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/elephant.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
            ["23123"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "fred.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/fred.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
          }    
         [1]=>
          array(10000) {
            ["624245"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(46) "duck.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(149) "Volumes/animals/duck.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2650752"
            }
            ["934522"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "lora.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/lora.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
            ["832452"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "sam.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/sam.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
          }
        [2]=>
          array(1500) {
            ["234214"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(46) "chi.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(149) "Volumes/animals/chi.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2650752"
            }
            ["942134"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "ape.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/ape.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
            ["234234"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["dateTime"]=>
              string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
              ["fileName"]=>
              string(45) "cat.jpg"
              ["path"]=>
              string(171) "Volumes/animals/cat.jpg"
              ["size"]=>
              string(7) "2306688"
            }
        }
    }
```

I compare them with this function:

```
    function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2){
                    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
                        if(is_array($value)){
                            if(!isset($array2[$key])){
                                $difference[$key] = $value;
                            }
                            elseif(!is_array($array2[$key])){
                                $difference[$key] = $value;
                            }
                            else{
                                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                                if($new_diff != FALSE)
                                {
                                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value){
                            $difference[$key] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
                }


                echo "<pre>";
                print_r(array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2));
                echo "</pre>";
```

The result is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["12345"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(46) "monkey.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

But what I would need is no matter where the difference is, I need always the path to be in the array too. I tried to add `$value["path"]` to the array `$difference` but do not really know how to do it.

The result I would need is:

```
 array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["12345"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["fileName"]=>
          string(46) "monkey.jpg"
          ["path"]=>
          string(46) "Volumes/animals/monkey.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'v changed your function and now it works as you expected:

```
efunction array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2){
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        if(!isset($array2[$key])){
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
        elseif(!is_array($array2[$key])){
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
        else{
            $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
            if($new_diff != FALSE)
            {
                $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
            }
        }
    }
    elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value){
        $difference[$key] = $value;
        $difference['path'] = $array1['path']; // added this feature here
    }
}
return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
```

}

Comment: As you can see, Akshay Khairmode used only $array1 values as result output, so we only need only its 'path' field. Now, we need to place this field value in $difference with the field that differs from such in $array2. And this particular place is inside of top level "else if" part. This part is the "bottom" of this recursion. 

I post those explanation as answer to user question, but this question was deleted. So I just keep it here. May be some one will need it for something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2){
                    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
                        if(is_array($value)){
                            if(!isset($array2[$key])){
                                $difference[$key] = $value;
                                $difference['path'] = $value['path'];
                            }
                            elseif(!is_array($array2[$key])){
                                $difference[$key] = $value;
                                $difference['path'] = $value['path'];
                            }
                            else{
                                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                                if($new_diff != FALSE)
                                {
                                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                                    $difference['path'] = $new_diff['path'];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value){
                            $difference[$key] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
                }


                echo "<pre>";
                print_r(array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2));
                echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: the result of the test: `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["12345"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(10) "monkey.jpg"
    }
    ["path"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["path"]=>
  NULL
}`

Comment: can you echo $value['path']; in place of $difference['path'] = $value['path']; and check if value is being printed

Comment: Yes, it is printed one time.